# “Close as duplicate” on Meta shows question text in a low contrast colour

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

I just voted to close a question as a dupe on Meta. When you suggest a candidate dupe, the close window shows you your chosen dupe and all the answers, so that you can read it without opening a new tab or window.

Except… it’s kind of hard to read.

[image]

(Safari 8.0.3, OS X Yosemite 10.10.2)

Comment: @phantom42 Are you getting that far into the close process?  The search results are fine, but the preview of the dupe looks the same as his screenshot here in OS X 10.10.1 Firefox 35.0.1.

Comment: @Keen, my mistake. I thought the screenshot was showing the search results. Yeah, FF has low contrast for the chosen dupe page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. The change will be on live after next production build(within 24 hours).

Comment: Yep, I see the fix.